# Hypothesis - reuse @given between tests

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

I've been using `hypothesis` for some time now. I'm wondering how I could reuse `@given parts`.

Some of the ones I have are like 20 lines and I copy the whole `@given` part above a couple of the test cases.

A simple example of a test

```py
@given(
    some_dict=st.fixed_dictionaries(
        {
            "test1": st.just("name"),
            "test2": st.integers()
            }
        )
    )
def test_that uses_some_dict_to_initialize_object_im_testing(some_dict):
    pass
```

What would be the best way to go around reusing `@given` blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your own decorator:

```
def fixed_given(func):
    return given(
        some_dict=st.fixed_dictionaries(
            {
                "test1": st.just("name"),
                "test2": st.integers()
            }
        )
    )(func)


@fixed_given
def test_that_uses_some_dict_to_initialize_object_in_testing(some_dict):
    pass
```

Answer (score 6):

Strategies are designed as composable objects, there is no problem with reusing them.

Thus an alternative to the accepted answer simply store configured sub-strategies as reusable globals e.g.

```py
a_strategy = st.fixed_dictionaries({ "test1": st.just("name"), "test2": st.integers()})

@given(some_dict=a_strategy)
def test_uses_some_dict_to_initialize_object_im_testing(some_dict):
    ...

@given(some_dict=a_strategy, value=st.integers())
def test_other(some_dict, value):
    ...
```

The [timezones](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#time-zone-arithmetic) examples shows that pattern, it defines an `aware_datetimes` strategy and uses that strategy in multiple tests, composed with a variable number of siblings.